# c# Restart numbering list in word with Interop or Aspose

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, aspose

I have a problem with ApplyListTemplate in Interop,
This method restart numbering even for not numbered paragraph

I used this code:

```
            this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range().ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
            ListTemplate: this.Application.ActiveDocument.ListTemplates[listNumber],
            ContinuePreviousList: false,
            ApplyTo: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList,
            DefaultListBehavior: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);
```

The problem is that a paragraph that has no list numbering applied returns 1 – whereas it really ought to return nothing or 0, or 10, or 9999, or something that indicates that it has no List Level – but certainly not 1. This is a bug.

Moreover, I have an Aspose liscence if you have a solution with that.

Comment: Please see if http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/439438/aspose-word-list-number-restart-continue-control.aspx can help using Aspose.Words. DO you want to restart all numbered paragraphs or selected? A sample document and the desired operation will help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to fix the problem.

```
 int listNumber = 1;
 foreach (Paragraph p in this.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs)
        {
            if (p.Range.ListFormat.ListType != WdListType.wdListNoNumbering)
            {
                p.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(
                    ListTemplate: this.Application.ActiveDocument.ListTemplates[listNumber],
                    ContinuePreviousList: true,
                    ApplyTo: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList,
                    DefaultListBehavior: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);
            }
        }
```